# Remote desktop fails in kiosk mode

Tags: remote-desktop, kiosk

I have a Windows 8.1/10 system running in kiosk mode. By clicking on a button created for this purpose, a remote desktop connection must be made. What happens is that in kiosk mode this connection is not initiated, but if I open the Windows explorer and taskbar appears, pressing the button starts the connection and connects to the remote desktop.
I think some necessary process is not running due to being in kiosk mode, but I dont know which. Any idea?

Comment: Which version of RDP are you using? - `mstsc.exe` or the one from the Microsoft Store? Does the problem also arrive on Windows 8.1?

Comment: Im using mstsc of Windows 8.1.

Comment: Are you using a Kiosk type of Single App or Multi App? Have you included RDP in the apps?

Comment: I create a buttons to run multi apps. For exemple, browser or email client works fine, I click in the button and it opens, but with remote desktop not, only if I open windows explorer before.

Comment: Maybe you could try using the RDP version from the Microsoft Store.